# Login in controller mangento2

Tags: magento2, controllers, frontend, login

I would login by controller in this way:

```
      $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate("paolomondillo@gmail.com","provaprova");
      $this->_session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
      $this->_session->regenerateId();
```

But in this way I'm not really logged:
[image]

Instead of:

[image]

What I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only speculate since the execute method isn't complete, you can debug some more using `var_dump(_SESSION)`after those lines, expecting `customer_id` not empty.

After that, try mimic the original action

`vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php`

```
$redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard')
    && $redirectUrl)
{
     $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
     $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
     // URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
     $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
     return $resultRedirect;
}
```